# Removing CollectionView cell class from array?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift3

I am creating a wizard using UICollectionView with an array of CollectionViewCells:

```
var viewCells:[BaseCVCell] = [createEventSubjectSearch(), createEventEventForm()]
```

This array is dynamically added to based on a series of UISwitch's that the user controls. I can add to the array fine using the code below, however I can't seem to remove an item when a user turns the switch off.

```
func switchToggled(sender : UISwitch) {

    if sender == createDiarySwitch {
        if sender.isOn {
            parentClass?.viewCells.append(createEventDeferEvent())
        } else {
            if let i = parentClass?.viewCells.index(where: { $0 == createEventDeferEvent() }) {
                parentClass?.viewCells.remove(at: i)
            }
        }
    }

    if sender == createDeferredSwitch {
        if sender.isOn {
            parentClass?.viewCells.append(createEventDiariseEvent())
        } else {
            if let i = parentClass?.viewCells.index(where: { $0 == createEventDiariseEvent() }) {
                parentClass?.viewCells.remove(at: i)
            }
        }
    }

    parentClass?.wizardCollectionView.reloadData()

}
```

I have tried the above code, as well as:

```
if let index = parentClass?.viewCells.index(of: createEventDiariseEvent()) {
    parentClass?.viewCells.remove(at: index)
}
```

Neither approach works (no errors, the code just never returns a value). I'd like to try and avoid naming elements where possible. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Is `BaseCVCell` a "data" class? Does `createEventDeferEvent()` return a new instance of that class? If so, you are trying to find a **new instance** of `BaseCVCell` in `parentClass?.viewCells`, so that will always fail.

Comment: BaseCVCell is custom CollectionViewCell class that handles the generic setup off all of my CollectionViewCells (although it's currently empty, so substitute it for UICollectionViewCell)

I tried running through the loop without the parentheses, but this fails to build with: Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'BaseCVCell' and 'createEventDeferEvent.Type''

Comment: Problem is that I need to pass the instance of each class back up to the array in the parent class and then reload the collection view against that so I can't instantiate anywhere else than when I append the array, unless I'm missing something?

Comment: Are you trying to create `UICollectionViewCell` *outside* of `cellForItemAt`?

Comment: Nope. The CellForItemAt uses a switch to check the class of the cell being rendered. All available cells are being registered. Parent class reference is being passed down to the cell that has the UISwitch's in

Comment: I'm confused then... you have `var viewCells:[BaseCVCell]` which is an array of `BaseCVCell` which you say is a subclassed `UICollectionViewCell`? But you are initially populating the array with `[createEventSubjectSearch(), createEventEventForm()]`, which is an array of what? If `createEventSubjectSearch()` returns a `BaseCVCell`, then you are somehow trying to create those cells *outside* of `cellForItemAt`... maybe edit your question to show your `createEventSubjectSearch()` function?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers, DonMag

I've achieved the desired functionality by instanciating the two dynamic cells in the main class:

```
let diariseCell : createEventDiariseEvent()
```

and then in the loop calling as thus:

```
if sender == createDiarySwitch {
    if sender.isOn {
        parentClass?.viewCells.append((parentClass?.diariseCell)!)
    } else {
        if let i = parentClass?.viewCells.index(where: { $0 == parentClass?.diariseCell }) {
            print("Found cell reference at index \(i)")
            parentClass?.viewCells.remove(at: i)
        }
    }
}
```

Works a charm now. Amazing what another pair of eyes can pick out!